# AttributeError: 'myclass' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, oop

If I have a class called `myclass` defined like this

`cl_test.py`

```
class myclass():
    def fx1(self, a):
        x = a
        print(a)

    def fx2(self, b):
        c = self.x + b
        print(c)
```

And I call both the functions in another Python file like this

`test.py`

```
import cl_test

var = cl_test.myclass()

var.fx1(5)
var.fx2(3)
```

Although the function `fx1(5)` gets executed and prints `5`, **BUT** while executing the second function `fx2(3)` it throws the following error -

```
c = self.x + b
AttributeError: 'myclass' object has no attribute 'x'
```

But the expected output of `fx2(3)` should be `8`.

Where Am I going wrong?

Comment: In fx1(), you need to change `x=a` to `self.x=a`

Comment: Cool, it works now, but why do I need to change `x=a` to `self.x = a` ?

Comment: You need to specify a convention in python so that instance variables can be recognized within a class. 'self' is this convention. Until unless you you do `self.x`, `x` alone is just a local variable to that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `fx1`, the variabe `x` is local to the method, you may assign it as an attribut of `self`

```
def fx1(self, a):
    self.x = a
    print(a)
```

But also, you may initialise this attribute in the `__init__`, because if not, if calling `fx2` without `fx1` you'll the same error, becase you'd have never assigned `x`, the following code allow to call with initial value `var = cl_test.myclass(2)` or without and it'll be 0 `var = cl_test.myclass()`

```
def __init__(self, x=0):
    self.x = x
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `self.x` to the first function. Just placing `x` as a variable there makes it accesable only in this function. Using `self.x` makes it accesable in the whole class.
Here is how your final for `myclass()` should look like:

```py
class myclass():
    def fx1(self, a):
        self.x = a
        print(a)

    def fx2(self, b):
        c = self.x + b
        print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, in fx2() there it do not know what is variable `x`. So, for fixing it you need to write `self.x` except just x to reference x with the object.

The end result:

```
class myclass():
    def fx1(self, a):
        self.x = a
        print(a)

    def fx2(self, b):
        c = self.x + b
        print(c)
```

and:

```
import cl_test

var = cl_test.myclass()

var.fx1(5)
var.fx2(3)
```